# Fatal Erro Database

Tags: php, banco-de-dados

Estava instalando um site, depois de tudo concluído abro o site e me deparo com este erro:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_select_db() in /home/imwfzgbi/public_html/config/config.php:19
>   Stack trace: #0 /home/imwfzgbi/public_html/index.php(15): include() #1 {main} thrown in /home/imwfzgbi/public_html/config/config.php on line 19

Config.php:

```
<?php
    $siteA = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/';
    $siteB = '/';
    $email_suporte_staff = 'darkshadownbt@gmail.com';

    global $siteB;
    global $siteA;

    $config_bd = array(
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'db' => 'imwfzgbi_ultra',
        'usuario' => 'imwfzgbi_flix',
        'senha' => 'ultraflixbr',
    );

    $conect = mysql_connect($config_bd['host'], $config_bd['usuario'], $config_bd['senha']);
    if($conect)
    {
        mysql_select_db($config_bd['db']);
        mysql_set_charset('utf8');
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<center><b>config/config.php</b> nao configurado.</center>';
        exit;
    }
?>
```

Esses são os arquivos com o suposto erro. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Qual a versão do PHP que você está a usar?

Comment: Versão PHP: 5.6

Comment: Certifique-se se o `mysql_*` está habilitado no *php.ini* (utilize `phpinfo();` para isso). [Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/579/99718)

Comment: cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit
; Manual editing of this file may result in unexpected behavior.
; To make changes to this file, use the cPanel MultiPHP INI Editor (Home >> Software >> MultiPHP INI Editor)
; For more information, read our documentation (https://go.cpanel.net/EA4ModifyINI)

display_errors = Off
max_execution_time = 200
max_input_time = -1
max_input_vars = 10000
memory_limit = 1024M
post_max_size = 128M
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
session.save_path = "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php70"
upload_max_filesize = 128M
zlib.output_compression = Off

Comment: esse e o php.ini

Comment: o driver mysql é obsoleto, já faz uns anos. Use Mysqli, ou PDO